# Select the second cell of each row in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table and I was able to select the first cell of each row successfully, but I can not use the same code to select the second cell of each row. Please help me select and change the CSS of the second cell of each row. The reason that I don't use normal CSS is because these are future cells of a table.

```
$("#part_rows tr td:first-child").css("width","150px");
```

The above one works fine, but the following does not work.

```
$("#part_rows tr td:second-child").css("width","150px");
```

Comment: `$("#part_rows tr:nth-child(2)")`??

Comment: **`0%`** accpet rate is not being very respectful of community that helps you when you've asked 11 questions already

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`nth-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
$("#part_rows tr td:nth-child(2)").css("width","150px");
```

If you plan to use jQuery, an hour spent browsing through the [entire list of jQuery methods and selectors](http://api.jquery.com/) will save you a lot of time down the track...

> *"the reason that I dont use normal css because these are future cells of a table."*

Did you try with "normal" CSS? I think you'll find that it works on elements that are added dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for the [**`:nth-child` selector**](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#part_rows tr").find('td:eq(1)')
```

In jQuery combining `.find()` - you can use 2 nice guys that do the job pretty well. You can take a look:

http://api.jquery.com/find/ 
http://api.jquery.com/eq/ 
http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: change to: `$("#part_rows tr td:eq(1)").css('color','red');` only gets the single td that selector calls for. Although not really necessary to change width on all rows i guess